# Creating sessions based on timestamps and different location

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to create session based on Location and Timestamp. If location is new or time has exceed **15 minutes interval** then a new session is assigned to the record in the dataframe. Example below

```
Location      |               Time                  |     Session
    A                   2016-01-01 00:00:15                  1
    A                   2016-01-01 00:05:00                  1
    A                   2016-01-01 00:10:08                  1
    A                   2016-01-01 00:14:08                  1
    A                   2016-01-01 00:15:49                  2     
    B                   2016-01-01 00:15:55                  3
    C                   2016-01-01 00:15:58                  4
    C                   2016-01-01 00:26:55                  4
    C                   2016-01-01 00:29:55                  4
    C                   2016-01-01 00:31:08                  5
```

This is the code which, doesn't work for given problem.

```
from datetime import timedelta


cond1 = df.DateTime-df.DateTime.shift(1) > pd.Timedelta(15, 'm')
#OR
#15_min = df.DateTime.diff() > pd.Timedelta(minutes=15)

cond2 = df.location != df.location.shift(1)
session_id = (cond1|cond2).cumsum()
df['session_id'] = session_id.map(pd.Series(range(0,10000)))
```

I want a new session, if new location is found or 15 minutes are up for current location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `groupby` both `Location` and using [`pd.Grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Grouper.html) to bin into 15 minute intervals and Location, then use [`ngroup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html) to number each group:

```
df['Session'] = (df.groupby(['Location',pd.Grouper(key='Time',freq='15min')])
                 .ngroup()+1)

>>> df
  Location                Time  Session
0        A 2016-01-01 00:00:15        1
1        A 2016-01-01 00:05:00        1
2        A 2016-01-01 00:10:08        1
3        A 2016-01-01 00:14:08        1
4        A 2016-01-01 00:15:49        2
5        B 2016-01-01 00:15:55        3
6        C 2016-01-01 00:15:58        4
7        C 2016-01-01 00:26:55        4
8        C 2016-01-01 00:29:55        4
9        C 2016-01-01 00:31:08        5
```

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly I was searching for.